# Blazor set attribute background-color in a grid cell at runtime

Tags: attributes, blazor, background-color

Problem is: I have a grid (smart htmlelements) and when I add a row I want to set the background colour of a cell in the row to a value supplied in the data row - so the cell colour varies between rows.

To enable the ability to intercept the cell formatting I have a template on the column.  This is firing and I have the value (say `#AABBCC`) but I need to set the background-color of the style attribute of the div to this - and that is where life gets difficult.

[Edit: I have expanded the code and redefined the nature of the problem with things I tried that didn't work]

I wrote this

```html
<template id="colourTemplate">
  <div style="width: 100%; height:100%;">
    <div smart-if="value == value">
      ***<div @attributes=ColourFunction(#AABBCC) >{{value}}</div>***
    </div>
  </div>
</template>
<Grid @ref="cdfGrid1" DataSource=@dsColourDifference Appearance=@appearance>
  <Columns>
     <Column DataField="sample1" Label="Colour1" Template="@colourTemplate"> 
     </Column>
  </Columns>
</Grid>

      @code{ 
        Dictionary<string, object> ColourFunction(string value)
        {
          var dict = new Dictionary<string, object>();
          dict.Add("style", "background-color: " + value);
          return dict;
        }
      }
```

I need to push the cell value `{{value}}` into the background-color of the div.  The "value" is available as the div output {{value}} and in the smart-if  but not for the div attributes. So replace this line

```html
<div style="background-color: #AABBCC">{{value}}</div>
```

With something that uses the incoming cell `{{value}}` instead of the hard-coded `#AABBCC`. The following do not work:

```html
<div style="background-color: {{value}}">{{value}}</div>
<div style="background-color: @value">{{value}}</div>
<div style="background-color: @{value}">{{value}}</div>
<div style="background-color: @{{value}}">{{value}}</div>
<div style="background-color: @(x => {value;}">{{value}}</div>
<div style="background-color: @(x => {{value;}}">{{value}}</div>
//Last two based on the error message from attempt #3
//Code blocks delimited by '@{...}' like '@{ {value} }' for attributes 
//are no longer supported These features have been changed to use 
//attribute syntax. Use 'attr="@(x => {... }"
```

I tried attribute splatting (below) but I have the same issue of pushing the `{{value}}` into the function parameter that I have doing it inline.

This does not work (compile error)

```html
<div @attributes="ColourFunction({{value}})">{{value}}</div>
```

Comment: I dont see the need for templates in Blazor, you just create a component. The component can have parameters that pass the colour and cell value. Your function does work if you move the code block outside the `<template>`

Comment: Need a template.  The template is attached to a Grid and when the Grid has a new row added I need a column template to take the {{value}} of the cell and instead inject it into the background-color of the div - this is proving impossible to do.  I have tried using a function to build the attribute but I cannot get the {{value}} into the function parameter.

Answer (score 0):

The blazor way to do this is create a component for the cell contents:

`Cell.razor`

```
<div style="width: 100%; height:100%;">
    <If Condition="true">
        <div @attributes="@ColourFunction(Color)" >@CurrencyValue</div>
    </If>
</div>

@code {
    [Parameter]
    public string Color { get; set; }

    [Parameter]
    public double Value { get; set; }

    string CurrencyValue => Value.ToString("C2");

    Dictionary<string, object> ColourFunction(string value)
    {
        var dict = new Dictionary<string, object>();
        dict.Add("style", $"background-color: {value};");
        return dict;
    }
}
```

**Usage**

```
<Cell Color="red" Value="20"/>
```

Note: You dont have to use the dictionary approach to achieve this you could put `style="background-color: @Value;"` directly on the `<div>`. As the question was about splatting I only updated your function to use a string.

Working [REPL](https://blazorrepl.com/repl/QvaZbBQH44Q5eBja49)

Comment: Thanks for your response.  I have edited the question to reduce it to a single problem.  Effectively I need the correct syntax to take the {{value}} and push it into the background-color.  Your solution retains the fundamental problem of pushing the {{value}} into the ColourFunction.

Answer (score 0):

Tech support from HTMLElements has responded and it is an issue with their Grid component.  Can't be done as no access to "value".

Update: the guy from tech support at HTMLElements has a solution:

```html
<template id="colourTemplate">
  <div style="width: 100%; height:100%;">
    <!-- Note: this shows a few designer errors but works-->
    <div style="background:{{value}};">&nbsp;</div>
  </div>
</template>
<Grid @ref="cdfGrid1" DataSource=@dsColourDifference Appearance=@appearance>
  <Columns>
    <Column DataField="sample1" Label="Colour1" Template="@colourTemplate"> 
    </Column>
   </Columns>
</Grid>
```

1. Need to use background not background-color;
2. Need to use non breaking space as the div content to ensure it is displayed.

Answer (score -1):

No offense, but this is why I don't use 3rd-party stuff for Blazor.  If I have one problem, it could waste a day trying to figure out how someone else did something-- but I can write a control to do almost anything in an hour or two.  Blazor makes it almost laughably easy.

The only thing I'll use 3rd-party for is a full HTML editor, since that involves some very clever string parsing that I don't want to have to figure out on my own.  But tables?  Not worth.

Comment: No offense taken, wasted two days sorting this out.  You are right that all of the Blazor controls I have used have bugs, lack of functionality, and the documentation is hopelessly out-of-date referring to methods, events and properties that don't exist whilst others that do exist are not mentioned.

In fairness to HTMLElements I reported this on Friday and tech support was in touch on both Saturday and Sunday, with the solution emailed to me at 6:55 Monday morning.

Comment: Coming from ASP.NET Web Forms, I was a little alarmed at seeing there were no real prefab objects in Blazor-- no table designer, etc.  In the end, though, I now feel very comfortable designing all my own components, and I'm a 10x better programmer for it.  It really isn't hard to think of the logic for alternating row styles, or to add custom events to a div.